# bootstrap image height when resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new in html/css/bootstrap. I have aproblem with an image with a class of img-responsive. I can t figure out why it doesn t maintain the full height of the col-md-4 when I resize the window. The image has the size:640x426. It  keeps getting smaller in height and looks like is not centered. 
Here is the code

```
<div class="container-fluid">           <!-- BEGINNING OF FEATURES -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="features-wrapper right">  
            <div class="features-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>   <!-- ICON -->
        <div class="features-text">
            <h4 class="md-size">Simple design</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum asperiores accusamus ipsa alias quibusdam facilis omnis.</p>    
        </div>      <!-- features-text -->
      </div>        <!-- Wrapper-right -->

       <div class="features-wrapper right"> 
        <div class="features-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <div class="features-text">
        <h4 class="md-size">Simple design</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum asperiores accusamus ipsa alias quibusdam facilis omnis.</p>    
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>      <!-- END OF COL-MD-4 -->



    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="features-wrapper image">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/tablet-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="features-wrapper left">
            <div class="features-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <div class="features-text">
            <h4 class="md-size">Designed for your needs</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum asperiores accusamus ipsa alias quibusdam facilis omnis.</p>                
        </div>
     </div> 

     <div class="features-wrapper left">
            <div class="features-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <div class="features-text">
            <h4 class="md-size">Designed for your needs</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum asperiores accusamus ipsa alias quibusdam facilis omnis.</p>                
        </div>
     </div> 
    </div>                  <!-- END OF COL-MD-4 -->    
</div>                      <!-- END OF ROW -->
```

And here is the CSS

```
 div.features-wrapper.right .features-text{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

div.features-wrapper.left .features-text{
    padding-left: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


h4.md-size{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.features-icon{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.features-wrapper.right .features-icon{
    float: right;

}

.features-wrapper.left .features-icon{
    float: left;
}

.features-icon i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #286090;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working as expected. Responsiveness is based on width, not height. `img-responsive` makes the image 100% width of it's container (`col-md-4`). As the browser with shrinks, so does the image width. The height of the image adjusts proportionally (based on the HxW of the image).

You could force the image to be 100% height, but then **[it will appear distorted](http://www.codeply.com/go/dTlljS2D2F)**:

```
.image > .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Basically the viewport(browser) ratio is not same as the image's ratio. In this scenario, a background image may work better since `background-size:cover` uses both height and width according to browser size.

```
.bg-image {
    background-image:url(//placehold.it/640x426);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/5L6McSklPb

Comment: I tried to make it stay the same height when I resize so it looks it has the same height as other 2 columns. When the window has larger width the height is the same like other 2 columns but when i shrink the window I have the feeling is losing too much height.I saw somewhere an image like this in between 2 columns but that image kept its ratio when was resized the window and also had img-responsive class.I was wondering if i could do something similar but it could be a matter of size of the picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked adding it as background image instead of img

Answer (score 0):

This this can solve it.     `.img { width :100%}`